# My C "Hello, world!" program isn't compiling

Tags: c, visual-studio

I wanted to learn C, so I decided to start a C project and try out the canonical "Hello, world!" program in Visual Studio.

So I put this code in

```
#import <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello, world!");
}
```

and got three errors:

> IntelliSense: cannot open source file "C:/.../stdio.tlh"
>   IntelliSense: identifier "printf" is undefined
>   IntelliSense: PCH warning: cannot find a suitable header stop location. An intellisense
>   PCH file was not generated.

Apparently I'm setting up my project wrong or I don't have the header files I need or something like that.

I'm sure this seems like a really basic problem, but I haven't really used C before so I'm stuck and don't know what to do. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: You should probably get a good book, and throw away whichever source you're using at the moment.

Comment: #import is Objective-C :) You cannot pull that off with a standard C preprocessor.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's not any source's fault, just a silly mistake on my part--other languages I've used have always used `import`

Comment: @PeterOlson: Fair enough. Anyway, a good tutorial should help you get started and far beyond the level you're currently at -- good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not `#import`, it's `#include`.

Answer (score 8):

`#import` should be `#include`.

Comment: Wow, that was even simpler than I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use #include instead of #import

Answer (score 2):

Couple of points that others have not pointed out:

1. main() should return int
2. Your string literal argument to printf should have a new line.

Comment: #1 - not necessary  #2 - why?

Comment: @KevinDTimm -- C standard requires so.  Just to clarify, I was not saying the main function should have a return statement such as "return 0;", rather, I was saying that C standard deprecated implicit return of int many years ago.  The OP code omitted the return specification for main.  Take a look at http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/#voidmain

If the string literal for printf does not have a new line, the output is not flushed.

Finally, the OP indicated he was learning C.  The points were not towards getting the code to compile, rather to help getting it correct.